# relocation truncated to fit IMAGE_REL_AMD64_ADDR32NB

Tags: windows, macos, rust, mingw-w64, shellcode

I stumbled upon this article that explains how to make shellcodes in Rust and I wanted to give it a shot : https://kerkour.com/rust-execute-from-memory (Here is a link to the code from the author : https://github.com/skerkour/kerkour.com/tree/main/blog/2021/rust_shellcode)

I'm on a MacBook Pro M1 running macOS Ventura 13.4.1, my target is Windows 11 running on Parallels.

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "shellcode"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]

[profile.dev]
panic = "abort"

[profile.release]
panic = "abort"
opt-level = "z"
lto = true
codegen-units = 1
```

.cargo/config.toml

```
[build]
rustflags = ["-C", "link-arg=-nostdlib", "-C", "link-arg=-static", "-C", "link-arg=-Wl,-T../shellcode.ld,--build-id=none", "-C", "relocation-model=pic"]
```

src/main.rs

```
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use core::arch::asm;

#[panic_handler]
fn panic(_: &core::panic::PanicInfo) -> ! {
    loop {}
}

const SYS_WRITE: usize = 1;
const SYS_EXIT: usize = 60;
const STDOUT: usize = 1;
static MESSAGE: &str = "hello world\n";

unsafe fn syscall1(syscall: usize, arg1: usize) -> usize {
    let ret: usize;
    asm!(
        "syscall",
        in("rax") syscall,
        in("rdi") arg1,
        out("rcx") _,
        out("r11") _,
        lateout("rax") ret,
        options(nostack),
    );
    ret
}

unsafe fn syscall3(syscall: usize, arg1: usize, arg2: usize, arg3: usize) -> usize {
    let ret: usize;
    asm!(
        "syscall",
        in("rax") syscall,
        in("rdi") arg1,
        in("rsi") arg2,
        in("rdx") arg3,
        out("rcx") _,
        out("r11") _,
        lateout("rax") ret,
        options(nostack),
    );
    ret
}

#[no_mangle]
fn _start() {
    unsafe {
        syscall3(
            SYS_WRITE,
            STDOUT,
            MESSAGE.as_ptr() as usize,
            MESSAGE.len(),
        );

        syscall1(SYS_EXIT, 0)
    };
}
```

I have the `x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` target installed, I run the command :

> cargo build --target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu --release

I get this error :

```
me@mes-laptop shellcode % cargo build --target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu --release
   Compiling shellcode v0.1.0 (/Users/me/shellcode)
error: linking with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="/Users/me/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/binutils/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/node@18/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Users/me/.cargo/bin:/Users/me/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts:/Users/me/.local/bin:/Users/me/.local/bin:/Users/me/Documents/flutter/bin" VSLANG="1033" "x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc" "-fno-use-linker-plugin" "-Wl,--dynamicbase" "-Wl,--disable-auto-image-base" "-m64" "-Wl,--high-entropy-va" "/Users/me/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib/rsbegin.o" "/var/folders/2d/kxjf2nld6zg04tmszz2m6rfh0000gn/T/rustco8dLv9/symbols.o" "/Users/me/shellcode/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/shellcode-4a095e2651710be8.shellcode.a38f4d46-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "-L" "/Users/me/shellcode/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps" "-L" "/Users/me/shellcode/target/release/deps" "-L" "/Users/me/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/Users/me/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-01a96de2f41b0b44.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lgcc_eh" "-l:libpthread.a" "-lmsvcrt" "-lmingwex" "-lmingw32" "-lgcc" "-lmsvcrt" "-luser32" "-lkernel32" "-Wl,--nxcompat" "-L" "/Users/me/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib" "-o" "/Users/me/shellcode/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/shellcode-4a095e2651710be8.exe" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-no-pie" "-nodefaultlibs" "-nostdlib" "-static" "-Wl,-Tshellcode.ld,--build-id=none" "/Users/me/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib/rsend.o"
  = note: /Users/me/shellcode/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/shellcode-4a095e2651710be8.shellcode.a38f4d46-cgu.0.rcgu.o:shellcode.a38f4d46:(.pdata+0x0): relocation truncated to fit: IMAGE_REL_AMD64_ADDR32NB against `.text'
          /Users/me/shellcode/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/shellcode-4a095e2651710be8.shellcode.a38f4d46-cgu.0.rcgu.o:shellcode.a38f4d46:(.pdata+0x4): relocation truncated to fit: IMAGE_REL_AMD64_ADDR32NB against `.text'
          /Users/me/shellcode/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/release/deps/shellcode-4a095e2651710be8.shellcode.a38f4d46-cgu.0.rcgu.o:shellcode.a38f4d46:(.pdata+0x8): relocation truncated to fit: IMAGE_REL_AMD64_ADDR32NB against `.xdata'
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
          

error: could not compile `shellcode` (bin "shellcode") due to previous error
```